# Zend Framework: Use model of default module without prefix

Tags: php, zend-framework, configuration, model

Hey guys, I'm working on a module based zend framework application, which uses the following structure:

```
application
    modules
        backend
            controllers, models etc...
        frontend
            controllers, models etc.
```

Hence all frontend models would be initated by called new Frontend_Model_*()... 
But I dont like this solution, cause I want the models in the backend, too.

For the controller side, I used the following option within my application.ini:

```
resources.frontController.params.prefixDefaultModule = false
```

Now my Frontend_IndexController is simply called Index_Controller.
Is there a simple way to do the same for models, forms, etc?

Which means a call like "new Model_*()" should lead directly to the frontend module, which is the default module. To call a backend model I had to use "new Backend_Model_*()"...

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: I'd recommend using modular directory structure (all modules with prefixes).

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get this thing working. In order to use autoloading in the case mentioned above, I had to do the following within my frontend bootstrap file:

```
protected function _initAutoload()
{
    $autoloader = new Zend_Application_Module_Autoloader(array(
        'namespace' => '',
        'basePath'  => dirname(__FILE__),
    ));
}
```

This sets the autoloading prefix to nothing, so one can initiate a frontend model through "new Model_*()". A backend model can still be initiated through "new Backend_Model_*()"

Note: The frontend bootstrap file is the only one, which should be touched in order to get this thing running!

Hope that helps somebody!

Comment: Not related, but if you use PHP 5.3, you can use \_\_DIR\_\_ instead of dirname(\_\_FILE\_\_)